# What is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\log(|\sin(\frac{1}{n})|)/\log(n+1)$

Tags: general-topology, limits, continuity, sequence-of-function

Find:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(|\sin(\frac{1}{n})|)}{\log(n+1)}$$

I decided to use continuous extension theorem to solve this indeterminate form. Is this rigorous and correct?

Define 
$$f_n(x)= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(|\sin(x+\frac{1}{n})|)}{\log(n+1)}$$
(Sequence of functions is not needed, but IMHO let’s one see more clearly the methodology)

Consider interval $(0,1]$

In this interval, $|\sin(x+\frac{1}{n})|>0 $ for all $n$, as well as when $n\to \infty$.

So the point-wise limit function $$f(x)= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(|\sin(x+\frac{1}{n})|)}{\log(n+1)} = 0$$

As $f(x) = 0$ is constant on interval $(0,1]$, it is uniformly continuous. So using continuous extension theorem:
[[image: 1]]
[Taken from page 10 of this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=mCmEZ-UtFBEC&pg=PA10&dq=continuous%20extension%20theorem%20amann&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi06eKB9ZPoAhUTqZ4KHXi4D1IQuwUILDAA#v=onepage&q=continuous%20extension%20theorem%20amann&f=false)

We must have a unique extension given by, $\bar f(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$.

Therefore,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(|\sin(\frac{1}{n})|)}{\log(n+1)}=0$$

I would like to emphasize: there may be other better ways to solve this, but I’m interested in finding if *this particular method* is rigorous and correct. and if there is any issues with it, could it be modified slightly to fix such issues.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The method is flawed.  The limit for $x=0$ is $-1$, not $0$.  The convergence is NOT uniform on any interval that contains $x=0$.

Comment: To state what is wrong with this argument, the function you define does have a unique continuous extension, but you haven’t justified why this extension would be equal to the limit you want (which you cannot do, because they aren’t equal). That is, you haven’t argued that the limit $g(x) = \lim_n f_n(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: May be I need to find a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large $n$, we have $\sin(1/n)\approx 1/n$, so $$\log\sin 1/n\approx \log 1/n=-\log n$$ so the limit is $-1$

Comment: Evidently, I had overlooked the “uniform convergence” requirement.